# How to pass data between sequential Commands?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, command-pattern

I have a client that wants to retrieve certain data based on the combined effort of two Commands. The reason I need two Commands is that the second command relies on data from the first Command. My question is what is the best way to pass data from the first command to the second command?

I'm using a coordinating object that is a delegate of the first and second command - but this seems messy. Is this resolvable in the layer where all the Commands are housed or does it require this coordinating object?

Here's a representation of the client class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CoordinatorDelegate {

    // ...

    @IBAction func didTouchButton(sender: UIButton) {
        self.coordinator.fetchSchoolID(firtName: "Jane", lastName: "Jones")
    }

    // MARK: - CoordinatorDelegate

    func fetchSchoolIDSucceeded(ID ID: Int) {
        self.updateUIWithSchoolID(ID)
    }

    func fetchSchoolIDFailed(error error: NSError) {
        self.displayError(error)
    }
}
```

The coordinator object:

```
protocol CoordinatorDelegate {

    func fetchSchoolIDSucceeded(ID ID: Int)
    func fetchSchoolIDFailed(error error: NSError)

}

struct Coordinator: FetchSchoolInfoActionDelegate, FetchStudentInfoActionDelegate {

    let actionFactory: ActionFactory
    var delegate: CoordinatorDelegate?

    func fetchSchoolID(firstName: String, lastName: String) {

        let firstAction = self.actionFactory.fetchStudentInfoAction(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, delegate: self)

        firstAction.execute()
    }

    // MARK: - FetchStudentInfoActionDelegate

    func fetchStudentInfoSucceeded(studentInfo: StudentInfo) {

        let secondAction = self.actionFactory.fetchShoolInfoAction(schoolName: studentInfo.schoolName, delegate: self)

        secondAction.execute()
    }

    func fetchStudentInfoFailed(error: NSError) {
        self.delegate?.fetchSchoolIDFailed(error: error)
    }

    // MARK: - FetchSchoolInfoActionDelegate

    func fetchSchoolIDSucceeded(schoolInfo: SchoolInfo) {
        self.delegate?.fetchSchoolIDSucceeded(ID: schoolInfo.ID)
    }

    func fetchSchoolIDFailed(error: NSError) {
        self.delegate?.fetchSchoolIDFailed(error: error)
    }

}
```

Summarily, the client (`ViewController`) wants to fetch the `schoolID` given a `firstName` and `lastName` of a student. To achieve this, two Commands need to be executed - `FetchStudentInfoAction` and `FetchSchoolInfoAction`. The second Command depends on data from the first Command - in this case, `FetchSchoolInfoAction` needs the student's `schoolName` that is retrieved by the `FetchStudentInfoAction`.

This seems messy. If we imagine that more requests are added to `ViewController`, the `Coordinator` object will get more and more complex. Is there a better way to deal with a set of sequential Commands when the second command requires data from the first? Could this be handled by an object at the Command layer instead of with the `Coordinator`?

Comment: What I've currently landed on is creating a new Command that itself becomes the delegate of the two Commands it's coordinating - and then having the object that I currently call `Coordinator` using just that one new action.

Answer (score 0):

The combined action (fetchSchoolID) hints at an entity/relation graph that could easily become more complex.   I would suggest that you add a completion handler pattern for returning the result of your asynchronous requests.

For example, if the execute() function provided a completion handler, you would be able to get a specific call back in the implementation of fetchSchoolID.

```
    let firstAction = self.actionFactory.fetchStudentInfoAction(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, delegate: self)

    firstAction.execute() 
    {
       (studentInfo) in
       let secondAction = self.actionFactory.fetchShoolInfoAction( ....
       secondAction.execute ...
    }
```

This would require a slight design change in your action factory (to store and call the completion capture but it will greatly increase the flexibility for combining and chaining actions.

To implement this in you action class you could do something like this:

```
class FetchStudent:YourBaseActionClass
{
   var completionHandler:((StudentInfo)->())? = nil

   // execute allow specification of a completion handler
   // but doesn't require it
   override func execute(completion:((StudentInfo)->())? = nil)
   {
      completionHandler = completion
   }

   // I assume you have something like this in here that
   // builds the StudentInfo before returning it through the delegate
   func fetchComplete() 
   {
      //... your code that prepared the student info
      completionHandler?(studentInfo)
   }

   ...
```

Comment: why i had avoided this in the first place is that all of my actions conform to a protocol (`Action`) that defines them as having just plain `execute()`. im wanting to maintain that so i can potentially do different operations with collections of `Action`s. do you see issues with combining the two into one new `Action` - e.g. `FetchSchoolIDAction` - that itself uses the `FetchStudentInfoAction` and `FetchSchoolInfoAction` internally and becomes their delegate?

Comment: Your delegate already has to deal with different function signatures depending on which action was triggered so the completion isn't adding more dependencies (it essentially has the same signature as the success function of the delegate).  [ more on the combined action desing in the next comment]

Comment: Combining the two action into one or allowing for ad-hoc combinations (through completion handlers or otherwise) is a long term design decision.   If your model has a great number of entities and is susceptible to re-combinations of use cases, flattening the action design will be harder to maintain. On the other hand, if you need to constrain the possible combinations to a strict pre-determined subset, then combined actions will provide the best level of control.

Comment: thanks for the insight. if you're willing to add this bit about the two paths to take in your answer, happy to accept it

Comment: In both cases, using completion handlers (either internally in your pre-defined meta-actions, or externally for arbitrary re-combinations) will make coordination much easier.  I'm not entirely sure that delegates are the best approach if you only intend to use them as a success/failure communication channel.